# Switch always outputting default value on guess a number game

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get a program to work that will guess which number the user is thinking of, however it currently only outputs the default switch action every time. Please tell me what I've done wrong? Thank you!

```
srand(time(0));
int lowernum = 1;
int highernum = 1000;
int number=rand()%highernum + lowernum;
string letter = "";
int letternum = 0;

cout<<"\nOkay, think of a number between one and 1000 
and I will try to guess it!\n";
cout<<"\nIs your number higher (h), lower (l) 
or exactly (e): " << number << "\n";
cin>>letter;

if (letter == "h")
{
    letternum = 1;
}
else if (letter == "l")
{
    letternum = 2;
}
else if (letter == "e")
{
    letternum = 3;
}

switch(letternum){
case'1': highernum = number; cout<<"\nIs your number higher (h), 
lower (l) or exactly (e): " << number << "\n"; cin>>letter;
    break;
case'2': lowernum = number; cout<<"\nIs your number higher (h), 
lower (l) or exactly (e): " << number << "\n"; cin>>letter;
    break;
case'3': cout<<"\nWahoooooo! I win! :D\n";
    break;
default:cout<<"\nI don't understand what you just typed in.\n";
    break;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`letternum` is an integer, your switch statement is using characters (e.g. '1'), just remove the quotes from the characters in your case expressions:

```
switch(letternum){
case 1:
```

etc...

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I missed that. However, my application has another problem; it doesn't get a new random number, it just keeps churning the same one out every time. Any ideas why?

Comment: I can't see the loop where you loop back to generate another number. Do you have one?

Comment: Nope. How would I get the program to loop back round? A while loop on the cin?

Comment: Well, you have other problems in there, but the loop should surround the computer generating a guess and the query to the user if it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Because your switch labels are chars, but your letternum is an int, so they dont match.